# iOS app to run continuously in background

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want my iOS apps to run continuously in background 24/7
I tried many options like background location updated with background task expiration handler, but later after some times it seems that the application gets suspended in background and user is brought back to the root view controller.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the reason you want you app to keep running in the background? Because Apple is very strict about background running, so misusing one of the background modes might get you app rejected.

Comment: There is no way to have your app continuously running in background because it will always be removed from memory if the device is running low, to which it will restart. Also what `rckoenes` said

Comment: What are you trying to build ?

Comment: Do iOS kills background apps when the battery consumption goes down by certain extent. can u specify after how much consumption of battery level do iOS starts killing background apps?? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For tasks that require more execution time to implement, you must request specific permissions to run them in the background without their being suspended. In iOS, only specific app types are allowed to run in the background:

- Apps that play audible content to the user while in the background, such as a music player app
- Apps that record audio content while in the background
- Ap ps that keep users informed of their location at all times, such as a navigation app
- Apps that support Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP)
- Apps that need to download and process new content regularly
- Apps that receive regular updates from external accessories
- Apps that implement these services must declare the services they support and use system frameworks to implement the relevant aspects of those services.

Declaring the services lets the system know which services you use, but in some cases it is the system frameworks that actually prevent your application from being suspended.

Comment: Do iOS kills background apps when the battery consumption goes down by certain extent. can u specify after how much consumption of battery level do iOS starts killing background apps?? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi sorry for my late answer.

Comment: As per my understanding, OS will not terminate app if battery level goes down. Apps will remain on the background.

Answer (score 3):

You should read this page of Apple Programming Guide : [Background Execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

It is not allowed to run background tasks 24/7. But you can use many different ways.

Comment: how long can an app execute in the background mode?

Comment: I use background in many applications for Location updates. It works all the time as long as it has battery.

But if you try to use Location updates and you don't use it, and don't prove to Apple Review team that you use it, they will not valid your app.

Comment: Do iOS kills background apps when the battery consumption goes down by certain extent. can u specify after how much consumption of battery level do iOS starts killing background apps?? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: With my experience, no iOS does not kill your app because of battery consumption. But I handle it by turning off background location updates when battery level is to down. So I cannot answer this question at 100%.

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't. Apple don't give any mean for an app to ensure background execution. iOS will give you processing time whenever it feel like it, and you cannot control that.